'Loading' text ( loader ) in task pane while initial loading in word web add-in
I'm currently developing a task-pane based Word web add-in. However, I'm encountering an issue when I try to sideload the add-in. The add-in shows a persistent loading screen (see attached image). I'm not sure how to resolve this problem.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Attached Image:
snapshot
I was expecting to remove that loader.
Tried "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml  --no-debug",
but it didn't working for me.

I've seen this where the "Loading" remains after the task pane has rendered. Is that what you're seeing or is the task pane just never rendering?

Thank you @RickKirkham for your quick response.
yes, I am referring to "Loading" remains after the task pane has rendered.
I have added my own loader ( spinner ) so I want to remove that "Loading".

I don't know if that "Loading" is supplied by Office or by code in the project. Was the project created with Yo Office? Can you search the code for "Loading"?

The "Loading" I am referring is not from my code.
yes, it was created with Yo office.
I searched for the term, there is no "Loading" in my entire code base.

This looks like a bug, and it might be a known one. Please go to the Issues for the office-js repo and search to see if it has already been reported. If not, please create a new bug report.

Thank you @RickKirkham for your help, I take necessary step.
